# Dynamic Mapping Statement in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In my code I change a DF into an RDD to run a function through a map call. With each run there is a couple seconds of overhead so if I run the function call like this:

```
var iterator = 1

val inputDF = spark.sql("select * from DF")

var columnPosition = Array("Column_4")
columnPosition = columnPosition ++ Array("Column_9")
var selectedDF = inputDF
var intrimDF = inputDF
var finalDF = inputDF

val inputDF = spark.sql("select * from DF")
while(iterator <= columnPosition.length) {
  selectedDF=finalDF.selectExpr("foreign_key",columnPosition(iterator))
  intrimDF = selectedDF.rdd.map(x => (x(0),action(x(1)))).toDF.selectExpr("_1 as some_key","_2 as " columnPosition(iterator)).joinBack.changeColumnPositions.dropOriginalColumn.renameColumns

  finalDF=intrimDF
  iterator = iterator + 1
}
```

It runs in ~90 seconds for a large job, because of the join. What I am trying to do is build it like below to cut out the join entirely and have be dynamic.

```
val inputDF = spark.sql("select * from DF")
val intrimDF = inputDF.rdd.map(x=>(x(0),x(1),x(2),action(x(3)),x(4),x(5),x(6),x(7),action(x(8))))
val columnStatement//Create an Array with columnName changes
val finalDF = intrimDF.selectExpr(columnStatement :_*)
```

The issue is I cant get past the hard coding side the problem, below is an example of what I want to try to do by dynamically setting the mapping call.

```
val mappingStatement = "x=>(x(0),x(1),x(2),action(x(3)),x(4),x(5),x(6),x(7),action(x(8)))"
val intrimDF = inputDF.rdd.map(mappingStatement)
```

Everything I have tried failed:
  1 Calling using the Map() function
  2 Setting an Array and passing it as :_*
  3 Trying to build it as an  calling, but it doesnt like being dyanmic

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: What about using an udf instead of map? It looks to me as you want to do an action on two of the columns, correct?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by join back. Can you explain it further (maybe with a simple example)?

Comment: What exactly you try to achieve?